# Where is the downloaded package files directory?

Tags: upgrade, updates, package-management, packaging

Where can I find the location of downloaded `.deb` files?

I want to copy this folder before I reinstall Ubuntu so I don't have to redownload the packages.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to reinstall? Is something broken? You could install from CD and choose not to install updates during installation (I hope this option is still available), though this would still download some packages like language files. Then copy the contents of `/var/cache/apt/archives` into the same directory on the new partition and run update.

Comment: thanks alot . i need to reinstall because i may remove linux and install it again , so i dont want to download the packeges again and again .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The .deb packages that you have already downloaded in apt-get are stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.

Comment: thanks , can i install them later if i have a backup of this folder ?
for example , if want to give this folder to a friend who has no internet access to install the backups ?
totally i mean HOW TO INSTALL PACKAGES WHITOUT DOWNLOADING THEM , JUST BY HAVING THE .deb FILES ?

againg , thanks

Comment: That should be possible. See my comment under the question.

Comment: i checked it , that was right . thank you . it can be installed from a cd . do i need to do more or if i just copy .dep files into cd is enough ?

Comment: I don't know if the installer will pick up the newer packages if you put them on the CD and could just guess into which directory to put them on the CD. Manually copying the files back to `/var/cache/apt/archives` after installation would be easier than reading up on how to produce respins/remasters of installation media.

Comment: @sepehr Also take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline or http://askubuntu.com/search?q=update+offline